# How to set domain.com/web/app.php to domain.com in symfony3

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

Basically, what I want is, when someone types mysite.com/$1, I do not want shown url to change in the address bar and actually runs mysite.com/web/app.php/$1

I added this line to my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1
```

And this line to my /web/.htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: is the standard .htaccess file not working? https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

Comment: no it is not working @FrankB

Comment: have you enabled `mod_rewrite`? or, are you using `nginx`? then, why are you using `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure nginx. You can find an example on "[The minimum configuration to get your application running under Nginx is:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)"

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    root /var/www/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

You may need to change `server_name`, `root` and `fastcgi_pass`.